# issue with exporting redux in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I usually export the components by this way:

```
export {Login} ;
```

Then import them in `index.js` file by this way:

```
export * from './login';
```

Then import them in each screen i want by this way :

```
import {Login, Header, Footer} from './index.js'
```

Now i am using redux in my project and i should use `connect` when i export my components by this way:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {emailChanged})({Login});
```

But i am getting following error

How should i export `Login`component ? ( Please keep in your mind i need to use index.js file to export my components, then i can not export them separately)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want specific name for the Component. you can create const and pass it in export.

```
   const LoginComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, {emailChanged})({Login});
   export { LoginComponent };
```